# Running X86 Assembly on Win8 64 bit

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm

I'm new to assembly and am trying to create replicate the folium of descartes (x^3 + y^3 - 3*a*x*y = 0 where a=12). I have the code done and when i compile and link, i get no error. Im using TASM through DOSBox 0.74 on a win8 64-bit. But when i try to execute the folium.exe file though the DOSBox, i get lines of random characters with it saying unable to open file in the center of the random characters. I dont know why such is happening, it should show '0' or ' ' according to my code. Either im assembling wrong or something is wrong in my code that im not aware of.

In DOSBox 0.74, i simply type `TASM folium.asm`, then `LINK folium` and then `folium` to execute. Thats the way i did it for my other code and it worked.

```
title   folium.asm  ; draws the loop in a cubic curve called the folium of Descartes, defined by x^3 + y^3 - 3*a*x*y = 0, where a = 12
    .model  small
    .stack  100h

    .data
    include const.inc

x   dw  ?
y   dw  ?
z   dw  ?

    .code

main    proc

; initialize DS
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

; y := 0;
    mov y, 0

while01: ; y <= 20
    cmp y, 20
    jnle    endwhile01

; do01
; x := 0
    mov x, 0

while02: ; x <= 20
    cmp x, 20
    jnle    endwhile02

; do01
; z := x*x*x + y*y*y - 36*x*6
    mov ax, x
    imul x
    imul x
    mov z, ax
    mov ax, y
    imul y
    imul y
    add z, ax
    mov ax, 36
    imul x
    mov bx, ax
    mov ax, 6
    imul bx
    sub z, ax

; if01 z <= 0
    cmp x, 0
    jnle    else01

then01:
; write '0'
    mov ah, dispstr
    mov dx, offset '0'
    int dosfunc
    jmp endif01

else01:
; write ' '
    mov ah, dispstr
    mov dx, offset ' '
    int dosfunc

endif01:
; x := x + 1;
    inc x
    jmp while02

endwhile02:
; write cr, lf
    mov ah, wrchr
    mov dl, cr
    int dosfunc
    mov dl, lf
    int dosfunc 

; y := y + 1
    inc y
    jmp while01

endwhile01:

; return -- to DOS
    mov ah, ret2dos
    int dosfunc
main    endp
    end main
```

Comment: Can you show what the values of `dosfunc`, `wrchr` and `dispstr` are? In your `int dosfunc ; mov dl, lf ; int dosfunc` you should probably reload `mov ah, wrchr` before the second `int dosfunc` since it's not clear that the `int dosfunc` will preserve the value of `ah` when executed. Is `dispstr` set to `09h`? If it is, then `ds:dx` needs to point to a string in memory terminated by a dollar sign (`$`). I don't think `offset '0'` or `offset ' '` will work there. You're going to get some really weird output from whatever is at those locations in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mov dx, offset '0'` and `mov dx, offset ' '` **don't** produce a string nor an offset to a string. TASM replaces '0' just with the ASCII code (30h), so the instruction will be `mov dx, 30h` and at DS:0030h is no '0'.

I don't know `const.inc`. I guess there are defines like:

```
dosfunc = 21h
ret2dos = 4Ch
dispstr = 09h
wrchr = 02h
cr = 0Dh
lf = 0Ah
```

The MSDOS function [`Int 21h / AH=09h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) (`mov ah, dispstr; int dosfunc`) expects in `DX` the offset to an ASCII string which is '$'-terminated. Don't forget the '$', else the output won't stop!

Insert into the `.data` section:

```
zero db '0$'
space db ' $'
```

Change

```
mov dx, offset '0'
```

to

```
mov dx, offset zero
```

and

```
mov dx, offset ' '
```

to

```
mov dx, offset space
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I wasnt taught what was in const.ini or how dispstr work, just how to use them to display string. So thank you very much and ill remember this for next time.

Answer (score 0):

If `dispstr` is DOS function `09h` then it requires the pointer to a string in memory where that string is terminated by a dollar sign (`$`). You can't just load `offset ' '` or `offset '0'` into `dx`, as x86 assembly doesn't implicity generate an address which points to a string. Instead, it's going to take the ASCII value of `' '` or `'0'` and load that as an address, which points at some odd place in memory, and thus the strange output you're seeing.

If you want to print a single character, you should just use DOS function `02h`:

```
mov ah, wrchr
mov dl, '0'
int dosfunc
```

This sequence also looks suspicious. It's not clear that the DOS interrupt `21h` will preserve the value of `ah`:

```
mov ah, wrchr
mov dl, cr
int dosfunc
mov dl, lf
int dosfunc
```

So it would be safer to reload it:

```
mov ah, wrchr
mov dl, cr
int dosfunc
mov ah, wrchr
mov dl, lf
int dosfunc
```